# Simple DB query - GAE cloudSQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a DB of size 50GB where the number of columns are 12. I have indexes on few of the columns. I am unable to get results from a simple query.

```
SELECT id, subscriber, name, time_ac, type,message, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_ac) AS time FROM logs WHERE domain = 'domain' AND type = 'type' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

I have indexes on id, subscriber, name, time_ac, type, domain.

I don't get the results quickly. I am using GAE so, I have 60 seconds to get the results which is failing now with the current query.

Comment: you don't *have* to get the results so quick, you could return to the user straight away but with a token they can use to get the results when they are ready. So the page might "poll" the server occasionally until the results are ready.

Comment: With a dataset of 50GB you could give a try at Big Query and compare performances for your specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make you query work faster you could add a multi-column index, for your `domain` + `type` + `time` columns (or at least `domain` + `type`):

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON logs (domain, type, time);
```

If you have just separate indexes on *few of the columns*, only one of them is used, and all other columns are processed w/o index. Take a look at [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) for your query also.